# How to force slick slider to make a full slide even if the next slide doesn't have enough elements to make a full slide?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My point being: if I have `two` slides and I want to display 4 elements per slide, but only have 6 elements in total, it would be represented as follows:

`First slide:` 1 2 3 4

`Second slide:` 3 4 5 6

But I want it to display the `second slide` as `5` and `6` only and make it go around a full lap, is this possible and if so - has anybody done that and can show me how to do it as well?

**Edit**

The slick structure is basically as follows:

```
<div class="products">
  <div>...</div>
  <div>...</div>
  <div>...</div>
  <div>...</div>
  <div>...</div>
  <div>...</div>
</div>
```

Slick options:

```
    $('.products').slick({
      dots: false,
      infinite: true,
      speed: 300,
      slidesToShow: 4,
      slidesToScroll: 4,
      responsive: [
        {
          breakpoint: 950,
          settings: {
            slidesToShow: 3,
            slidesToScroll: 3,
            infinite: true,
            dots: false
          }
        },
        {
          breakpoint: 760,
          settings: {
            slidesToShow: 2,
            slidesToScroll: 2,
            infinite: true,
            dots: false
          }
        }
      ]
    });
  }
```

Comment: Please can you share your HTML structure, relevant css and slick options?

Comment: @SimonMason well I've updated what I've got, the css doesn't really matter it's more of a slick as a slider thing